# Is it better to put Facebook SSO in onCreate or onStart Method?

Tags: android, facebook, oncreate, onstart

Is it better to put the Facebook Single Sign on Authentication process in the onCreate or onStart method?

In the facebook tutorial si never said to preferably put in either one of them, but doing some test on my own, I see the screen pit black until the access_token is got by the SDK and given to my main Activity.

So I was wondering if putting the whole process in the OnStart method would create any security issue or data inconsistency.

Comment: just a side note: when you test your app, make sure you have the facebook app downloaded. log in to the facebook app and then try logging into facebook from your app. weird things might happen..

Answer (score 1):

As you noted in the question, it is better to do the Facebook SSO in the onStart. While in the process of SSO, display ProgressDialog.

Answer (score 0):

It is upto your requirement. If the task you are targeting needs to be done every time activity comes to foreground, you have to do it in onStart(). If you want it to be done on the creation and not needed on every restart then you can do it in Oncreate(). Basically this is the basic difference between oncreate() and onStart()